# How to custom the deform Form?

Tags: python, pyramid, deform

When I use the default deform Form. It's not what I need.

How to custom it ?

For example, I need this:

```
firstname:[_______]  lastname:[_______]
*username: [____________________] alink
```

where [*_*_] represent normal html input.

Should rewrite the template?

Comment: In what way is this not what the default form generates?

Comment: default deform generate firstname[_] and lastname[_] in seperated lines

Comment: Aha, I see. I wold probably solve that with CSS, but overriding the form works as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a css issue, to provide a custom CSS class to a deform input you need to use the following:

```
text_input = deform.widget.TextInputWidget(
    css_class='yourdivnamehere')
```

Then inside deform you can:

```
first_name = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String(),
            widget = text_input)
```