# Customising location of input tags on Deform Form

Tags: css, deform

I would like to have several input boxes side by side (horizontally) in a deform form but can't work out how to do it.

So I found this question and I thought I had the answer.

[How to custom the deform Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930864/how-to-custom-the-deform-form)

I would rather use css than override the template.

Trouble is I don't know what the css should look like. I did want to comment on the other question but I am too new!

what does 'yourdivnamehere' look like?

Or is there a data grid alternative widget for deform that I could use?

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I have been off work. Oh and formatting this comment is not great. I have created a jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/jogilder/z1bbtugw/ I want the personal name component parts (name and value) to sit side by side instead of below each other. To do this I need to create a widget: text_input = deform.widget.TextInputWidget(
    css_class='yourdivnamehere')  and then I use the widget in my deform form.

Comment: In fact I would like all the personal name components to be along side each other so each personal name is on one line.